# In what units is the Thrust-to-Weight ratio expressed?

Tags: units

is it correct to say the units for T/W is s^2/m?

This is what I did:

T/W= s/ft * ft*lb/s * s^2/lb*ft

Comment: It doesn’t look right.  What units are you using for Thrust by itself and what units for weight by itself?

Comment: No. It should be unit-less. lb-f/lb-f = nothing

Comment: Yes, unitless.......

Comment: Thrust to weight would be a dimensionless ratio.  It sounds like you’re trying to write impulse to weight.

Comment: Newtons/Newtons = f/f = ma/ma ...

Answer (score 8):

Thrust is a force. Weight is a force. Regardless of what unit one uses for each (Newtons, pounds, etc), the ratio of two forces is a pure number without any units. A T:W ratio of 1 means the thrust and the weight are equal, a ratio of 2 means that the thrust is double the weight, and so on.

It would be comprehensible to say "2 Newtons of Thrust per Newton of Weight", but "Newtons per Newton" isn't really useful, and that scenario would also be "2 pounds per pound," since the thrust is twice the weight. So simply "2" is how it's expressed - a pure number.